# Springboot API placing requests on a queue?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have been developing a REST API using spring boot for some time now. I have a strange problem..

The API works perfectly, I can make many API calls and push data successfully to our system. Although every once in a while an issue arises where it seems to get stuck processing incoming requests, when I send them to the API nothing happens / no code is called!

I am starting the .JAR using a .bat script, I noticed when I send a request and it hasn't come through / received it, if on the CMD window I press "CRTL + C" Suddenly all the requests that hadn't come through or been received flood through!

It seems as though something is blocking them / placing them on a queue. It is very strange as this only happens every once in a while. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do the client recieve an OK or a timeout?

Comment: @NikolajHansen They receive a timeout, but after the CTRL+C I still get the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes happens for me as well in a cmd prompt. I use command prompts in quick edit mode. Sounds like you may have accidentally highlighted some text in the prompt. This will pause all processing in the cmd prompt.
If you press Esc to unselect any marked/highligted text, your application should continue to run normally again.

Comment: wow, thanks! This was the solution. I must have accidentally clicked the CMD when checking the logs